# Can't use binding.break in docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker-compose, ruby-debug

I am running a Rails 7 app through docker-compose. When I try to use `binding.break` in the code, my attached terminal shows something like the following:

```
web        | Started POST "/media_uploads" for 172.19.0.1 at 2022-07-02 20:57:26 +0000
web        | Cannot render console from 172.19.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
web        | [29, 38] in /web/config/initializers/rack_attack.rb
web        |     29|   end
web        |     30|
web        |     31|   # Intended to prevent bulk upload overloading, but may have other consequences
web        |     32|   throttle('posts/ip', limit: 1, period: 1) do |req|
web        |     33|     if req.post?
web        | =>  34|       binding.break
web        |     35|       req.ip
web        |     36|     end
web        |     37|   end
web        |     38|   ### Prevent Brute-Force Login Attacks ###
web        | =>#0       block {|req=#<Rack::Attack::Request:0x00007fa9990ffc...|} in <class:Attack> at /web/config/initializers/rack_attack.rb:34
web        |   #1       Rack::Attack::Throttle#discriminator_for(request=#<Rack::Attack::Request:0x00007fa9990ffc...) at /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-attack-6.6.1/lib/rack/attack/throttle.rb:53
web        |   # and 50 frames (use `bt' command for all frames)
```

but doesn't provide me with an input buffer to enter commands. I have to kill the process in order to do anything on the server. My docker-compose includes

```
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

but it still doesn't work. Any ideas what to try?

Comment: I also faced this problem. I noticed that if I attach the terminal before sending the request that will arrive at "binding.break" it works like a charm, but if I send the request and then try to attach, the attachment works, but I can't type anything. I hope it works for you too. Unfortunately, I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

EX: I have a docker-composer.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: anywork_db
    env_file:
      - .db.env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  app:
    image: anywork:latest
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - entrypoint.sh
    build: .
    container_name: anywork_app
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/AnyWork
    env_file:
       - .app.env
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - db
    # command: puma
    # sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .
```

If you debug, you must access container_name of app with `docker attach container_name`.

EX: docker attach anywork_name. It is work for you.